# How to find the resulting transformation for any vectors given only two examples?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a T: R^2 ---> R^3

and v1 = (1,1) . T(v1) = (1,0,0)

and v2 = (2,1) . T(v2) = (0,1,0)

I am asked to verify that T(1,0) = (-1,1,0)

Knowing that it's true, I want to understand how the following was found:

**T(x,y) = (2y - x)T(v1) + (x - y)T(v2) = (2y-x, x-y, 0)**

From where does the (2y - x) and (x - y) come from?
**Why does the equation work?**

Comment: Hint : $v_1$ and $v_2$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's express $(x,y)$ in terms of linear combination of $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$.

That is let's write $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\end{bmatrix}=c_1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} + c_2\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Of which, we can write in an equivalent matrix multiplication form, $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence $$\begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\c_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=-\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$

That is $c_1 = -x+2y, c_2=x-y $

Note that by linearity, we have $$T(x,y)=c_1T(1,1)+c_2T(2,1)$$

Comment: What does the matrix(1, -2, -1, 1) represents. Does it have a name?

Comment: The columns consists of $v_1$ and $v_2$, they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: then what is the matrix(1, 2, 1, 1) represents?

Comment: why does the equation T(x,y) work?

Comment: I have included more details.

Comment: Ok so because v1 and v2 are a basis of R^2 knowing where they land after their linear transformation allows use to know where every other vector lands. Is it why the formula works?

Comment: yup, the linear relationship still holds after the linear transform.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the role of c1 and c2 in all of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91752/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-dr-stone).