# How do I find the transformation matrix $A$ given $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ only?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$

I am given two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ and their LT $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$.

$v_1 = (1,1) \cdot T(v_1) = (1,0,0)$ and $v_2 = (2,1) \cdot T(v_2) = (0,1,0)$.

How do I find the matrix of transformation $A$?

I know that it involves writing $T(v) = Av$  but I don't have a clue in how to proceed. **Now I've also found that we can represent the transformation with this equation:** $$T(x,y) = (2y - x)T(v_1) + (x - y)T(v_2) = (2y-x, x-y, 0)$$

Comment: The answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168439/265466) gives you a way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** I think that you want $A$: the matrix of  $T$ in the standard basis $(e_1,e_2)$ where $e_1=(1,0)$ and  $e_2=(0,1)$. Notice that $e_1=v_2-v_1$ so $T(e_1)=T(v_2)-T(v_1)=(-1,1,0)$. Similarly we have $e_2=2v_1-v_2$... (I leave the details for you to complete the matrix.)

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&\star\\1&\star\\0&\star\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is the second column (2, -1, 0)?

Comment: Yes!${}{}{}{}{}$